# Convert factor to logical in one step

Tags: r, data.table

Is it possible to convert my factor column `X` to a logical column in one step using data.table's "in-place" methods?

```
myDT <- data.table(X = factor(c("true", "false")))
str(myDT)

myDT[, X := as.logical(X)] # does not work

myDT[, X := as.logical(as.character(X))] # does not work either

# but this does
myDT[, X := as.character(X)]
myDT[, X := as.logical(X)]
str(myDT)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update your `data.table` installation; this was a bug fixed, from version 1.9.8, and now `factor`s can be converted to `logical`s directly.

```
library(data.table)
myDT[, X:= X=="true"]
str(myDT)
#Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  2 obs. of  1 variable:
# $ X: logi  TRUE FALSE
```